# How can I debug Sitecore in case inbuilt personalization rule not working?

Tags: personalization

I have set up simple persona rule in banner rendering. Persona is set on the user and I can confirm it from Experience profile but still my rule is not executed. I have tried rule for both contact and visit but for both the cases it is not executed. How can I debug or check logs related to this issue.

Comment: Can you please provide the rules that you have used and also, make sure that there are no caching set on the banner rendering

Answer (score 3):

I would start by installing this tool https://github.com/buildabonfire/Bonfire.Analytics.Dto. Then when in session you can see who patterns you are current in (past and present). If you see the persona you expect. Then I would move to the log files and see if you have a null reference to a profile key in an items tracking field. When you rename a profile, it can cause issues like this.

```
{
   "CurrentProfiles":[
      {
         "ProfileName":"Industry",
         "Score":10.0,
         "Count":1,
         "PatternName":"Business Services",
         "PatternId":"ea29b725-905b-4ab2-b6b5-727dbb479514",
         "PatternLabel":"Business Services"
      },
      {
         "ProfileName":"Focus",
         "Score":10.0,
         "Count":1,
         "PatternName":"",
         "PatternId":null,
         "PatternLabel":null
      }
   ],
   "PastProfiles":[
      {
         "ProfileName":"Industry",
         "Id":"8c78d1ec-e978-4ef7-a27f-f70038548230",
         "NumberOfTimesScored":1,
         "Total":0.0,
         "Scores":[
            {
               "Key":"a8e663b6-b1cc-45a0-b2d6-dda85218d050",
               "Value":10.0
            }
         ],
         "StringScore":null,
         "PatterneName":"Business Services",
         "PatternId":"ea29b725-905b-4ab2-b6b5-727dbb479514"
      }
   ]
}
```